# Arduino Temperature Display

Tags: arduino, system, temperature

i have a little 2,4" tft touch display, and i want to display Information like Temperature of the CPU and the GPU, and the usage of the CPU cores. i tried getting the temperature with wmic and the MSAcip_ThermalZoneTemperature. but my system does not support that. Could someone tell me a way to get the Temperature and the other information without buying any extra hardware? My Mainboard: Asus M5A78L/USB3 (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A78LUSB3/)

Thanks, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Without extra hardware, the best way I can think of is to write a program for your computer that is able to pick up temperature statistics from your mainboard, then have that speak to your Arduino via Serial over USB.

The other option I can think of would involve finding out where the temperature probes on your mainboard live and physically tapping into those and reverse engineering how they work.  However, this stands a very high chance of voiding warranties and ruining your board.

Comment: Could you do something like this for me? Because i am not really into programming (except arduino and a bit of java).

Comment: No, but [Arduino Playground has a very nice guide to do this in Java](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java).  Hava a crack at it, and if you run into any issues, just put up a new question for us.